# Line connection (instead of arrow) in mermaid

Tags: r, diagrammer, mermaid

I'm trying to create a mermaid chart in R. The syntax seems to be quite straightforward - however I haven't found a possibility to make **line connections** between two shapes **without** an arrow head.

In this example:

```
     mermaid("
        graph LR
            sq1[shape one]-- This can't be a shape. So sad. --> sq2[shape two]

            cyr1((circle one))-->cyr2((circle two));
      ")
```

will get
[image]

Here, the connection between "shape one" and "this can't be a shape" is a line, but as soon as I try to use this connection between two shapes the output won't construct a diagram. Is there any way to realize a line connection between two shapes?

Comment: Are you open to an alternative way to get the same with diagrammer?

Comment: Yes I am. Are you referring to grViz? With that package I had the problem of left-to-right direction of the graphs. Any pointers? :)
For the sake of the thread of this post please post answers for other packages in the comments (like you already did). Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As to DiagrammeR documentation, connection could be defined as:

```
--> arrow connection
--- line connection
```

So you simply need:

```
mermaid("
        graph LR
            sq1[shape one]-- This can't be a shape. So sad. --- sq2[shape two]
            cyr1((circle one))---cyr2((circle two));
      ")
```

Comment: Geez that was easy, thanks! I didn't find that in the documentation though before.

Comment: You'll find the documentation of mermaid here: https://mermaidjs.github.io/flowchart.html